# Can we use multiple currency type in a website using X-Cart

Tags: php, x-cart

Can we use multiple currency type in a website using X-Cart. For example is it possible to use both USD price and AUD price for a single product or different products in a single web-site using X-Cart.

Answer (score 0):

If you use X-Cart GoldPlus or Platinum, you may SHOW PRICES in several currencies. It's possible due to 'multicurrency' module ( which is built-in to the versions above, and is a separate paid add-on for X-Cart Gold): http://www.x-cart.com/extensions/modules/multicurrency.html
It's actually for customer's convenience  - he will no longer need to recalculate the cost into his local currency.

However as I understand you want not only to SHOW, but also to PROCESS orders in different currencies. By default it's not possible, but you may want to consider such a custom modification ( from $549): http://mods.x-cart.com/Advanced-Multi-Currency-Support.html